# how to make each bar stand out (with border) in grouped barplot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

```
structure(list(coord = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L), .Label = c("21906057-21916057", 
"21916057-21926057", "21976057-21986057", "21986057-21996057", 
"22006057-22016057", "22016057-22026057", "22036057-22046057", 
"22046057-22056057", "22056057-22066057", "22066057-22076057", 
"22076057-22086057", "22096057-22106057", "22106057-22116057", 
"22116057-22126057", "22126057-22136057", "22136057-22146057", 
"22146057-22156057", "22156057-22166057", "22166057-22176057", 
"22176057-22186057", "22186057-22196057", "22196057-22206057", 
"22206057-22216057", "22226057-22236057", "22236057-22246057", 
"22246057-22256057", "22256057-22266057", "22306057-22316057", 
"22316057-22326057", "22326057-22336057", "22336057-22346057", 
"22346057-22356057", "22356057-22366057", "22366057-22376057", 
"22426057-22436057", "22436057-22446057", "22446057-22456057", 
"22466057-22476057", "22476057-22486057", "22506057-22516057", 
"22516057-22526057", "22526057-22536057", "22536057-22546057", 
"22546057-22556057", "22556057-22566057", "22566057-22576057", 
"22576057-22586057", "22586057-22596057", "22596057-22606057", 
"22606057-22616057", "22616057-22626057", "22626057-22636057", 
"22636057-22646057", "22646057-22656057", "22686057-22696057", 
"22726057-22736057", "22736057-22746057", "22746057-22756057", 
"22806057-22816057", "22816057-22826057", "22826057-22836057", 
"22836057-22846057", "22866057-22876057", "22876057-22886057", 
"22886057-22896057", "22896057-22906057", "22906057-22916057", 
"22916057-22926057", "22956057-22966057"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", 
    "gene4", "gene5"), class = "factor"), value = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 43L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 31L, 31L, 
    31L, 31L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 9805L, 72L, 74L, 74L, 
    74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 2187L, 0L, 40L, 54L, 54L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 62L, 
    62L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 3L, 40L, 40L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 200L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 49L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 
    36L, NA, 1L, 54L, 54L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 72L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 40L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 31L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), exp = c("Extremely low", 
    "Very Low", "Extremely low", "Extremely low", "Extremely low", 
    "Extremely low", "Moderately high", "Extremely low", "Extremely low", 
    "Extremely low", "Extremely low", "Extremely low", "Extremely low", 
    "High", "High", "Moderately high", "Moderately high", "Moderately high", 
    "Moderately high", "Low", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
    "Very Low", "Moderate", "Extremely high", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Extremely high", 
    "Extremely low", "Moderately high", "High", "High", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Very Low", "High", "High", 
    "Very Low", "Moderately high", "Moderately high", "Moderately high", 
    "Very Low", "Moderately high", "Moderately high", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Very high", "Extremely low", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Extremely low", "Moderately high", NA, NA, "Extremely low", 
    NA, "Extremely low", "Extremely low", NA, "Moderately high", 
    NA, "Very Low", "High", "High", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Extremely low", 
    "High", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Extremely low", NA, NA, NA, "Low", 
    "Moderately high", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Extremely low", NA, NA, NA, "Very Low", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "High", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Extremely low", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Extremely low", NA, NA, NA, "Low", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Extremely low", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Moderate", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Moderately high", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("coord", 
"variable", "value", "exp"), row.names = c(NA, -345L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot this data as grouped barplot using ggplot2.
I performed these steps:

```
test[is.na(test)] <- 0
```

---

```
q<-ggplot(test, aes(x=coord, y=value, fill=factor(exp))) + geom_bar(aes(fill=exp),stat="identity",position = "dodge")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

The bars which come in indiviual groups are not well-defined, can I border each of the bars in the group?

I also tried this:

```
barchart(log10(value) ~ coord, groups=exp, test, auto.key = list(columns = 3))
```

But I cannot control things like rotating the x-axis labels. However, I will prefer ggplot2 as I have to add another layer of data wherein i have to highlight few x-axis labels which will be by referring another dataset and merging to the existing 'test' d.f. This I have done for few plots using help from SO question/answers so not a problem.

UPDATE:
As log10(0) will give -Inf values, is doing
scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", expand = c(0,0))
correct?

Comment: Add `col = 'black'` to `geom_bar`.

Comment: @Axeman: The coordinate 22036057-22046057, which is 7th label on x-axis, should have 2 bars. These are falling in the same 'exp' category. Even after colour="black", I get only one bar. I want to show them as two separate bars.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after, perhaps you want to include `group = variable` in the `aes`.

Comment: @Axeman:  This helped :) i got now what i wanted. Thankyou!